# Query across two SQLite databases in Delphi TFDQuery

Tags: sql, sqlite, delphi, firedac

Is there a way to do an inner join across 2 database SQLite files, when they both uses different sqlite passwords?

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.some_id = table2.some_id 
WHERE table1.some_id = 5
```

where table1 is from 1st database file and table2 is in the 2nd sqlite database file.

Comment: Yes. You can attach another external SQLite database to your primary SQLite database. Then you can query across the two.

https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-attach-database/

Comment: sorry, I meant to be more specific. is there a Delphi way of doing it?

Comment: There is no "Delphi way". It's just SQL.